# mongo db or redis for a facebook like site?

Tags: python, django, database-design, mongodb, redis

I'm building a social app in django, the architecture of the site will be very similar to facebook

There will be posts, posts will have comments

Both posts and comments will have meta data like date, author, tags, votes

I decided to go with nosql database because of the ease with which we can add new features.

I finalized on mongodb as i can easily store a post and its comments in a single document. I'm having second thoughts now, would REDIS be better than mongo for this kind of app?

**Update:**
I have decided to go with mongodb, will use redis for user home page and home page if necessary.

Comment: I suggest you delete this question before it get's downvotes - since it too bloated. If you are a good software designer with an emphasis on scaleability, you can create scaleable app with files, if you are a bad tactician on the war with traffic, you'll lose even though you are using the best software.

Comment: "the architecture of the site will be very similar to facebook. There will be posts, posts will have comments" I had no idea facebook was so simple :)!

Comment: Fscebook uses MySQl. Lots of the web's biggest sites use MySQL or some other relational database (SO uses MSSQL). There are sound reasons for this. Read some of the case studies on HighScalability: http://highscalability.com/blog/category/example Realise what you're losing before you jump into NoSQL. Build a core set of features well before worrying about ease of adding new ones.

Comment: go for mysql. http://www.quora.com/Quora-Infrastructure/Why-does-Quora-use-MySQL-as-the-data-store-instead-of-NoSQLs-such-as-Cassandra-MongoDB-CouchDB-etc/answer/Adam-DAngelo

Answer (score 2):

There's a huge distinction to be made between Redis and MongoDB for your particular needs, in that Redis, unlike MongoDB, doesn't facilitate value queries.

You can use MongoDB to embed the comments within the post document, which means you get the post and the comments in a single query, yet you could also query for post documents based on tags, the author, etc.

You'll definitely want to go with MongoDB. Redis is great, but it's not a proper fit for what I'd believe you'll need from it.

Answer (score 1):

These things are subjective and can be looked at in different directions. But if you have already decided to go with a nosql solution and is trying to determine between mongodb and redis I think it is better to go with mongodb as I guess you should be able to save a big number of posts and also mongodb documents are better suited to represent posts.

Redis can only save upto the max memory limit but is super fast. So if you need to index some kind of things you can save posts in mongodb and then keep the id's of posts in redis to access faster.

Answer (score 1):

As @APC commented maybe there is a reason why large sites go with SQL solutions. So here comes my proposal: "study what other large sites do".

e.g. [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) is I think one of the (if not **the**) biggest django deployments out there and specialize in discussions/comments. They use Postgresql and [David Cramer](http://justcramer.com/), who works there, says they're not planning on ditching it. So take a look about scaling comments [here](http://justcramer.com/2010/05/30/scaling-threaded-comments-on-django-at-disqus/) and [here](http://justcramer.com/2012/04/08/using-arrays-as-materialized-paths-in-postgres/).

I know it isn't a direct response to your dilemma but still, it might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

First, loosely couple your app and your persistence so that you can swap them out at a very granular level. For example, you want to be able to move one service from mongo to redis as your needs evolve. Be able to measure your services and appropriately respond to them individually.

Second, you are unlikely to find one persistence solution that fits every workflow in your application at scale. Don't be afraid to use more than one. Mongo is a good tool for a set of problems, as is Redis, just not necessarily the same problems.